# ¿Como guardar en un fichero de Objetos un maestro detalle de una factura?

Tags: java, archivo, poo

Objeto Albaranes:

```
public class Albaranes implements Serializable {

    private int id_albaran;
    private int id_cliente;
    private Date fecha_venta;
    private String comentario;
    private Articulos articulo;
```

Objeto Articulos:

```
public class Articulos implements Serializable{

    private int id_articulo;
    private int unidades;
    private int precio;
```

Tengo que guardar en el mismo fichero, 1 o más albaranes con todos los artículos del albarán.

Con los setters de cada clase puedo guardarlo, pero solo me guarda un articulo por albarán.

Aquí se guarda el objeto albarán:

```
albaran.setId_albaran(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldid_albaran.getText()));           albaran.setId_cliente(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldid_cliente.getText()));   
            SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            dateFieldfecha_venta.setDateFormat(formatoFecha);
            java.util.Date fecha = (Date) dateFieldfecha_venta.getValue();
            albaran.setFecha_venta(fecha);

            albaran.setComentario(jTextFieldcomentario.getText());


             CrearFichero.guardarNuevo(albaran);
```

Aquí se guardan los artículos:

```
articulo.setId_articulo(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldid_articulo.getText()));
       articulo.setUnidades(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldunidades.getText()));
       articulo.setPrecio(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldprecio.getText()));
       albaran.setArticulo(articulo);
```

Método de crear el fichero:

```
 public static void guardarNuevo(Albaranes albaran) {

        try {

            Properties propiedades = new Properties();

            propiedades.load(new FileInputStream("E:\\GradoSuperior2\\ExamenRecuperar\\ExamenAliciaDatos\\Examen\\ExamenAlicia\\src\\archivos\\GestionPropiedades.properties"));

            String nombre = propiedades.getProperty("nombreArchivo");

            //Coger la propiedad ponerle la ruta y la extension
            String archivo = "..\\Archivos\\"+nombre+".dat";


            //Nuevo
            String ruta = "..\\Archivos";
            File carpeta = new File(ruta);
            File[] listaArchivos = carpeta.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listaArchivos.length; i++) {
                File f = new File(archivo);    
                if (f.exists()) {

                   archivo = "..\\Archivos\\"+nombre+i+".dat";


                }
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(albaran);

            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
                fos.close();

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CrearFichero.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CrearFichero.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

El problema es que solo me guarda un articulo por albarán, y deberia guardarme todos los que yo quisiera, no se como hacer esto. ¿Alguna idea?
Gracias.

Comment: No está claro quieres guardar en un archivo? no veo el código donde serialices tu objeto hacia el archivo, creo que necesitas algo de la API de Collections https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html como List, Set o Map. podrías ser un poco más específico con lo que deseas.

Comment: Por que no compartes el codigo del método CrearFichero?, si usas la clase BufferedReader para agregar texto usa el metodo append, ya que si usas write solo escibira el ultimo dato insertado.

Comment: Actualice con el código de crear el fichero. Uso un ObjectOutputStream, para guardar los objetos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ocurre ya que Albaran tiene 1 articulo y no una lista de articulos. Deberias cambiar

```
private Articulos articulo;
```

Por

```
private Arraylist<Articulos> articulos;
```

Cuando crees y agregues 1 o mas articulos haces `albaran.articulos.add(articulo)`

Comment: Muchas gracias, A la hora de leerlo tendría que recorrer el arraylist de cada objeto albarán verdad?

Comment: Exacto! Esa es la ventaja de la lista